Is there a way to redirect components with links embedded when they are clicked in React?
I have a Navbar with the routes set up like this:
import '../styles/Nav.css'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Home } from '../components/Home'
import { Contact } from '../components/Contact'
import { Error } from '../components/Error'


export const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      
      {/* Nav Links */}
      <div className='nav-major-container'>

        <div className='logo-container'>
          <p>Logo h</p>
        </div>

        <nav className='nav-container'>
          <Link to='/' className='home-link'>Home</Link>
          <Link to='/contact' className='contact-link'>Contact</Link>
        </nav>

      </div>

      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact/>}/>


        {/* Error Route */}
        <Route path='*' element={<Error/>}/>
      </Routes>

    </Router>
    </>

  )
}


I want to be able to click the links and be redirected to a part of the page with the component, similar to the a href in html. For example, when I click the Contact component, I want to be redirected to the part of the page with the Contact.jsx
As shown above, setting up the routes only made it so that when I click any of the links in the navbar, it displays the component on the page. This is not what I want.

Do you mean something like <a herf="pathTo#contact"> but in react router?

Check this answer.

Yes, a anchor tag that will redirect to a certain part of the same page or a different page.

I haven't done nothing with react-router for a while now, i'd assume you can put the id of the html-element in hashtag # inside to-tag in Link-component just like the way you do it with the a-tag:
<Link to="#target"> Go to target! </Link>

I'm not sure if it'll work. But if not, please take a look here

I don't think that I have seen this in practice ,but I could be wrong though . Common approach is to use useRef like in the above answer would be interesting to see what happens though

You can use useRef() hook.
For example,
const contactRef = React.useRef();

const navigate = useNavigate(); // for navigation

After you click this button or link, add onClick function.
const handleClickContact = () => {
  navigate("/contact");
  contactRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
}


As another answer above mentions you could possibly use useRef Not sure if navigate() works or is required. However this is how I usually approach :


import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const aboutSection = useRef(null);

  const scrollTo = () => {
    if (aboutSection.current) {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: aboutSection.current.offsetTop,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="link" onClick={scrollTo}>
        About Us
      </button>

      <div className="about" ref={aboutSection}>
        <h2>About Us</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;



Alternatively you could check out react-router-hash-link its built on react-router and is a quick fix for the scroll 'issue'
